# python subprocess.run() wrongly parses command

Tags: python, makefile, subprocess

I use python to execute the shell commands. The command call make with some extra flags:

```
version_info = r"CXXOPTS+='-DVERSION=" + r'\"' + args.version + r'\"' + r"'" + \
                         " -DSOFTWARE_FLAVOR=" + r'\"' + args.software_flavor + r'\"' + \
                         " -DSOFTWARE_DECORATOR=" + r'\"' + args.software_decorator + r'\"' + r"'"
```

where args is the arguments parsed by ArgumentParser from the command line that called this python script.

Then I execute:

```
command = f"make {version_info} all"
subprocess.run(command, shell=True, encoding="iso-8859-1", check=True)
```

It reports error: unknown output-sync type FTWARE_FLAVOR.
It seems it cannot recognize -DSOFTWARE_FLAVOR.
Then I tried to split this command line as follows:

```
version = r"CXXOPTS+='-DVERSION=" + r'\"' + args.version + r'\"' + r"'"
flavor = r"CXXOPTS+='-DSOFTWARE_FLAVOR=" + r'\"' + args.software_flavor + r'\"' + r"'"
.....
```

Then it works correctly.

**What is the reason of this error?**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I run this code, I get `/bin/sh: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '`. Are you certain the code in your question matches the code you're running?

Comment: @larsks Maybe I remember wrong. I got both errors when I tried different by removing some quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your life becomes simpler if you drop the `shell=True` and pass a list to `subprocess.run`, because this allows you to drop much of the elaborate quoting you're using to create your command line.  For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
version_info = (
    f'CXXOPTS+=-DVERSION="{args.version}" '
    f'-DSOFTWARE_FLAVOR="{args.software_flavor}" '
    f'-DSOFTWARE_DECORATOR="{args.software_decorator}"'
    )

command=['make', version_info, 'all']
subprocess.run(command)
```

If I have a `Makefile` that looks like this:

```
all:
  echo CXXOPTS: "$(CXXOPTS)"
```

And I add some code to populate `args`:

```
import argparse
import subprocess

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--version', default='1')
p.add_argument('--software-flavor', default='vanilla')
p.add_argument('--software-decorator', default='martha.stewaret')
args = p.parse_args()

version_info = (
    f'CXXOPTS+=-DVERSION="{args.version}" -DSOFTWARE_FLAVOR="{args.software_flavor}" '
    f'-DSOFTWARE_DECORATOR="{args.software_decorator}"'
    )

command=['make', version_info, 'all']
subprocess.run(command)
```

Then I get as output:

```
echo CXXOPTS: -DVERSION="1" -DSOFTWARE_FLAVOR="vanilla" -DSOFTWARE_DECORATOR="martha.stewaret"
CXXOPTS: -DVERSION=1 -DSOFTWARE_FLAVOR=vanilla -DSOFTWARE_DECORATOR=martha.stewaret
```